# Angular JS : $http.get() data is not being updated to View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Script.js**

```
        var app=angular.module("myapp",["panelModule"]);
        var store=this;
        store.products=[];

        //following code yield proper output
        // app.controller("StoreController",function () {
        //  this.products=data; //data is a array of object defined in same file
        // });

        app.controller("StoreController",['$http',function($http){
            return $http.get('js/data.json').then(onDataReceive);
        }]);

        var onDataReceive=function(response) {
            store.products.push(...response.data);
            console.log(store.products); //this shows [object, object] in browser console

        };
```

I m basically iterating over the array of object with ng-repeat in my view( index.html) But it is not getting update when i used $http service.However static data is getting displayed properly.
I m going thru some online AngularJs tutorial. I m new to AngularJs. Please point me out what i m doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: What is the browser you are using?
Try using Array.prototype.push.apply(store.products, response.data) instead of store.products.push(...response.data);

Comment: Why are you using your `store` property and `onDataReceive` function outside of the controllers?

Comment: That code is really weird, why is `store` *outside* Angular? I really suggest you going through the [Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) so that you acquire the basics.

Comment: @Paraíso I m using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["panelModule"]);
app.controller("StoreController", ['$http', function($http) {
  var store = this;
  store.products = [];
  gettingAPIData();
  function gettingAPIData() {
    $http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response) {
        store.products. = response.data;
        onDataReceive();
    });
  }
  function onDataReceive() {
    console.log(store.products);
  };
}]);
```

This is the way to do it, you first create a method and do the http stuff in it. Call another method in the success response and print it out.

Comment: i got one doubt ... the function passed as success promise is anonymous right .. also the onDataReceive should be response. Please correct me if i m wrong

Comment: yes that's a typo `$http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response) {` here i'm not calling onDateReceive function, it's just reponse. edited & corrected.. Please try

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["panelModule"]);
app.controller("StoreController", ['$http', function($http) {
var store = this;
store.products = [];
getData = function() {
    return $http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });
}


// do the ajax call
getData().then(function(data) {
    // stuff is now in our scope, I can alert it
    store.products = $scope.data;
    console.log(store.products);
});
```